# Create job report across multiple java classes

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I am implementing a scheduled job that needs to create a verbose report.
A report example would look like this:

```
date - Started job 
date - Looking for stuff to process
date - Got x stuff to process
date - Processing y1
date - done
date - Processing y2
date - done
date - Processing y3
date - Failed with error : this_is_why_processing_failed
date - Processing completed
date - Job completed in z seconds
```

The actual code doing all the processing can be in multiple classes. 
The obvious way to implement something like this is to have a StringBuilder and pass it around so that messages get appended.

Another more advanced approach would be to create a singleton and have an id that is somehow known across all the classes that take part in the processing (could it be the Thread name?), and store the report string there.

Is there a better way to do this? 
Are there any best practices for creating job reports?

The job will be triggered using ejb timers.

Comment: Would you please improve the formatting of your report example?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing around a `StringBuilder` you should use a logger.
A singleton with a `ThreadLocal` member field could be a good place to store a "token" to use for all classes working for the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [Log4j](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-log4j-and-how-do-i-use-it.html) which was designed for just this reason.

Comment: You mean I should use or create a custom appender whose output is a String or some memory object and at the same time create one such log per thread. Ok I ll look into that.

Comment: You can use one per application (see use of tag). It is thread safe also.